# How to schedule a python script cron job that have packages in virtual environment?

Tags: cron, python, environment-variables

I have my env where I installed all needed for me packages. And where I have my script that I want to put to the crontab. What I did, but there are a problem that when crontab running my script, of course script can't be run due to missing packages, because they are only in my env.

So, first solution to install all packages on my host (but I don't want to do it)

Right my crontab look like this:

```
* * * * * /path/script.py
```

where script.py have `#!/usr/bin/python3.6`

and I need to include to my crontab somehow my env with all needed packages.

any idea?

Comment: You have to activate the environment within the script and set and also set any shell variables that you might be using inside of it before the commands are run that will use the environment and the variables (if you have any).

Comment: Can you write example of what I need to do, because I'm not sure that I'm understand you.

Answer (score 2):

I made script `cron_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/env/bin/activate
cd /path/to/script/
python3.6 script.py
deactivate
```

My crontab:

```
* * * * * /path/to/cron_script.sh
```